# How can i make a ListView's items take up all the available height?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to make a column chart using WPF. For the Y axis I have a list of values which I would like to display on the control.

I have a `ListView` bound to the collection. How can I get the items to spread over the entire length of the list view rather then squish together at the top? And is the `ListView`the correct control to use for this?

Here is a sample of my Xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding YAxisValues}" 
          Background="Gray" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                       Foreground="White" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       FontSize="12" Width="50"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image: Desired ListView]

On the left is the list view as i currently have it. 
On the right is my desired result.

How can I change my ListView to get there? Or do I need to use a different control entirely?

Comment: try wrapping the label in a `ViewBox` like this:
`<ViewBox>
     <Label Content="{Binding Path=Value}" Foreground="White" />
</ViewBox>`

Comment: @NorbertKovacs It didn't seem to change the outcome i'm afraid.

Comment: @Timmoth, another thought: `ListView` allows to select items from list. If you don't need selection, `ItemsControl` instead of `ListView` should work with the same success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with UniformGrid used as ItemsPanel items get equal height

```
<ListView Name="Axis" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding YAxisValues}"
        Background="Gray" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"              
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <!--no changes-->
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

there can be a issue when ListView doesn't have enough height for all elements. In that case I would put ListView into ViewBox

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.  In my case, if there aren't enough items to fill the space of a `ListBox`, then the `UniformGrid` gives the items the ability to share the extra space.  In the event that there are enough items for a scroll bar to appear, the height of each item goes to the minimum required height. Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Set `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` for items.

```
       <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I  want the items to take up as much room as they can vertically. But this solution doesn't seem to change it as far as i can see. (even when setting VerticalContentAlignment)

Comment: If you change it to `VerticalContentAlignment` and then change the `ListView.ItemsPanel` to `UniformGrid`, that should fix it, which is essentially ASh's answer.  The difference is that it doesn't matter if you set `VerticalContentAlignment` on the `ListView` itself or on its `ListView.ItemContainerStyle`.